# Make page reload (revalidate) on "back" without no-cache

Tags: http, http-headers, http-caching

I would like to have a user's browser refresh the page when they hit the back/forward button. However, I don't want to send a no-cache header. The browser is still supposed to cache the page (e.g. in case the connection drops the user should still be able to load it from cache).

Example: The user is on page A, navigates to page B. When they press "back", the browser shall either:

- make a full new request for A or
- make a request for A, possibly get "304 Not Modified", and serve from cache

When the user is on B and presses "back" after the network connection is severed, I want it to serve the page from cache.

I can't find any combination of headers that achieves this (seemingly sensible) behavior. From it's name I would guess `must-revalidate` would work as desired, but it doesn't. I tried different combinations of `public`, `max-age`, setting an expiry date in the past, etc., but couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions?